# Как отловить ошибку в action redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch, try-catch

У меня есть такой код запрос к сервису openweathermap.org

```
export const getWeather = (city) => async (dispatch) => {
    const res = await weather.getWeather(city)
    if(res.ok) {
        dispatch(setWeather(res.data)) // res data is undefined. WHY?
    } else  {
        dispatch(setError(res))
    }
}

const setError = (error) => ({
    type: "SET_ERROR",
    payload: error
})

export const setWeather = (weather) => ({
    type: "SET_WEATHER",
    payload: weather
})
```

Даже если я каким то образом не могу получить res.data, то как мне обработать ошибку через promise и then?

Так же у меня есть service который делает fetch запрос

```
const weather = {
    getWeather: async (city: string) => {
        const res = await fetch(api + `?=${city}` + `&appid=${apiKey}`);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Как мне обработать ошибку в action getWeather чтобы эту ошибку положить в состояние redux?

```
const initialValue = {
    weather: {},
    isLoaded: false,
    errors: {}
}

const weather = (state = initialValue, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        
        case "SET_WEATHER": 
            return {
                ...initialValue,
                weather: action.payload
            } 

        case "SET_ERROR": 
            return {
                ...initialValue,
                errors: action.payload
            }

        default: return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если у Вас вопрос как отловить ошибку в async/await, то тут все подробно написано :
https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: @GayratVlasov, В моем случае обычный try catch не работает, в fetch запросе есть ошибка и его статус 400, но в catch ошибка не обрабатывается!

Comment: Чудес не бывает :) Значит Вы не то в try/catch обернули. Судя по всему у Вас открытый проект - дайте ссылку на github.